# бинаризация в OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

если провести для изображения размытие по Гауссу (OpenCV, функция - GaussianBlur()), это будет считаться как провести бинаризацию изображения? То есть можно сказать, что GaussianBlur() == бинаризация? Или нет?
(извините за глупый вопрос)

Answer (score 3):

Нет, не будет. Бинаризация - это вполне конкретный результат, когда в каждом пикселе изображения есть только бинарное значение 1 или 0.

Результатом же размытия по Гауссу будет все то же изображение, с теми же каналами, только размытое по Гауссу.